# Reactjs: React-router-dom Cannot Read Property Push of Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Before you conclude that i have not combed stackoverflow very well, i will like to state that i have done that but i have not yet gotten the solution.

Good day guys, i have been having this issue for days, i was trying to push after clicking on a button but i cannot. I then tried to console.log this.props in the componentDidMount and it was showing an empty object.

This is the App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Layout from './hoc/Layout/Layout';
import BurgerBuilder from './containers/BurgerBuilder/BurgerBuilder';
import Checkout from './containers/Checkout/Checkout';

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact render = {routeProps => (
                <BurgerBuilder {...routeProps} />
              )}
            />          
            <Route path="/checkout" exact component={Checkout} />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is the burger-builder component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux_/Aux_'
import Burger from '../../components/Burger/Burger'
import BuildControls from '../../components/Burger/BuildControls/BuildControls'
import Modal from '../../components/UI/Modal/Modal'
import OrderSummary from '../../components/Burger/OrderSummary/OrderSummary'
import Spinner from '../../components/UI/Spinner/Spinner'
import withErrorHandler from '../../hoc/withErrorHandler/withErrorHandler'
import axios from '../../axios-orders'

const INGREDIENT_PRICES = {
    salad: 0.5,
    cheese: 0.4,
    meat: 1.3,
    bacon: 0.7
}

class BurgerBuilder extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ingredients:null,
            totalPrice:4,
            purchaseable:false,
            purchasing:false,
            loading:false,
            error: false
        }
    }   

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(this.props) 
        axios.get('/ingredients')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ingredients : response.data});
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({error: true})
            })
    }

    updatePurchaseState = (ingredients) => {
        const sum = Object.keys(ingredients)
                    .map((igKey) => (
                        ingredients[igKey]
                    ))
                    .reduce((sum, el) =>{
                        return sum + el
                    } ,0)
        this.setState({purchaseable: sum > 0})
    }

    addIngredientHandler = (type) => {
        const oldCount = this.state.ingredients[type];
        const updatedCount = oldCount + 1;
        const updateIngredients = {
            ...this.state.ingredients
        };
        updateIngredients[type] = updatedCount;
        const priceAddition = INGREDIENT_PRICES[type];
        const oldPrice = this.state.totalPrice
        const newPrice = oldPrice + priceAddition;
        this.setState({totalPrice: newPrice, ingredients: updateIngredients},
            this.updatePurchaseState(updateIngredients)
        )
    }

    removeIngredientHandler = (type) => {
        const oldCount = this.state.ingredients[type];
        if(oldCount <= 0){
            return ;
        }
        const updatedCount = oldCount - 1;
        const updateIngredients = {
            ...this.state.ingredients
        };
        updateIngredients[type] = updatedCount;
        const priceDeduction = INGREDIENT_PRICES[type];
        const oldPrice = this.state.totalPrice
        const newPrice = oldPrice - priceDeduction;
        this.setState({totalPrice: newPrice, ingredients: updateIngredients},
            this.updatePurchaseState(updateIngredients)
        )
    }

    purchaseHandler = () => {
        this.setState({purchasing:true})
    }

    purchaseCancelHandler = () => {
        this.setState({purchasing:false})
    }

    purchaseContinueHandler = () => {
        // this.setState({loading:true})
        // alert('You Continued')
        // const order = {
        //  ingredients: this.state.ingredients,
        //  price: this.state.totalPrice,
        //  customer:{
        //      name:'Durojaye Peter',
        //      address:{
        //          street:'Ire-Akari Estate 2',
        //          zipCode: '41351',
        //          country: 'Nigeria'
        //      },
        //      email:'oluleyepeters@gmail.com',
        //  },
        //  deliveryMethod:'fastest'
        // }
        // axios.post('/orders',order)
        //  .then(response => {
        //      this.setState({loading:false, purchasing:false})
        //  })
        //  .catch(error => {
        //      this.setState({loading:false, purchasing:false})
        //  })
        this.props.history.push('/')
    }

    render(){
        const disabledInfo = {
            ...this.state.ingredients
        };
        for(let key in disabledInfo){
            disabledInfo[key] = disabledInfo[key] <= 0
        }

        let orderSummary = null 
        let burger = this.state.error ? <p>Ingredients cannot be loaded</p> : <Spinner />

        if(this.state.ingredients !== null){
            burger = (
            <Aux>   
                <Burger ingredients={this.state.ingredients}/>
                <BuildControls
                    ingredientAdded={this.addIngredientHandler}
                    ingredientRemoved={this.removeIngredientHandler}                    
                    disabled={disabledInfo}
                    purchaseable={this.state.purchaseable}
                    price= {this.state.totalPrice}
                    ordered={this.purchaseHandler}
                />
            </Aux>
            );
            orderSummary = <OrderSummary 
                ingredients={this.state.ingredients}
                purchaseCanceled = {this.purchaseCancelHandler}
                purchaseContinued = {this.purchaseContinueHandler}
                price={this.state.totalPrice}
            />          
        }
        if(this.state.loading){
            orderSummary = <Spinner />
        }               
        return(
            <Aux>
                <Modal show={this.state.purchasing} modalClosed={this.purchaseCancelHandler}>
                    {orderSummary}
                </Modal>
                {burger}
            </Aux>
        )
    }
}

export default withErrorHandler(BurgerBuilder, axios)
```

As it is shown in the code,i was trying to console.log this.props in the purchaseContinueHandler but it keeps showing an empty object.

Thanks a lot guys any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where are those `routeProps` coming from?

Comment: i was thinking its just a way to pass the props down to the other coomponent......i am up for correction

Comment: Yes, it's a right way, but you have to define those props :)

Comment: k-wasilewski, please can you explain to me i am to do that.

Comment: It's very simple: what variables do you want to pass to this `BurgerBuilder` component?

Comment: I want to pass history and match

Comment: I guess they are available in a `Route`'s component by `this.props.history` and `this.props.match`, no need to pass anything explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the `basename` to the `Layout` component. Also try removing `Exact`.

```
<Layout basename={process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_PATH}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" render = {routeProps => (
            <BurgerBuilder {...routeProps} />
          )}
        />     
</Layout
```

Comment: Hey Nidhi, i tried this but its not working.....no difference......when i consoled.log this.props in the child component, it still returns an empty object.

Comment: Okay. May be it  is because you've given '/' to BurgerBuilder component and going back from this.history.push('/') to the same component. can you provide some name with '/'. Like '/burgers' ?

Comment: I get what you are saying, but from me console.logging this.props in componentDidMount of the BurgerBuilder component, i get an empty object. Thats why the error its returning an error of that it cannot push history of undefined.

Comment: you'll get the props only if you're sending something with prop. From which component you're passing state/ data. Try consoling there. is it sent properly?

Comment: I am getting the state from the burgerbuilder Component......., but i need the props to push

Comment: You mean you want to pass the state of burger builder to somewhere else and for that you need to call this.props.history.push which is not working cause of props ? if this is the case than remove the props from Route. and give props where you want to receive it. like receiving in checkout then pass props there not in burger builder.

Comment: Hey Nidhi, when using route, there are some props that ae automatically passed, they include match and history. This props are supposed to be available in the burger builder but they are not.....That is the issue i am facing